# Elasticsearch connector task stuck in failed and unknown status

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In my elasticsearch connector, the tasks.max was set at 10 which I reduced to 7. Now the connector is running with 7 tasks and the other three tasks are stuck at "unknown"  and "failed" status. I have restarted the connector but still the tasks did not get removed.
How do I make sure to remove these tasks which are unassigned/failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Kafka Connect. Unsure if there is a JIRA, or if even fixed in versions later than the last one I have used (approx Kafka 2.6).

When you start with a higher `max.tasks`, then that information is stored in the internal status topic of the Connect API, and this is what the status HTTP endpoint will return. When you reduce this value, those previous task's metadata are still available, but is no longer being updated.

The only real fix I've found, is to delete this connector, and re-create it, potentially with a new name since the status topic is keyed by the name.